# Small caps when referencing appendices

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, small-caps

I'd like to make a reference to Appendix A using a small cap A. Here you can see a MWE which works as expected when Babel is commented out.

**Q: Why does it fail when uncommenting Babel and how can I make it work with Babel?** After uncommenting Babel, the "A" becomes a normal capital letter.

Related question: **How can I make the "A" a small cap also in the Appendix heading?** Still not sure if I want that. I don't know what is the common practice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}% <-- This line breaks it when uncommented

\begin{document}
See appendix \textsc{\MakeLowercase{\ref{app}}}.

\appendix
\section{First appendix}
\label{app}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, an expandable version of `\ref` is needed in the form of `\getrefnumber` from the `refcount` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}% <-- This line breaks it when uncommented
\usepackage{refcount}
\begin{document}
See appendix \textsc{\MakeLowercase{\getrefnumber{app}}}.

\appendix
\section{First appendix\label{app}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Still don't know why using Babel breaks my MWE.

Comment: @Paapaa You are welcome.  I do not know the precise answer, but I do know packages like `babel` are very invasive to your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you *also* want to use small caps also the the appendix section titles, it's easy with `etoolbox`. Further, it's compatible with `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\appendix}{\renewcommand\thesection{\textsc{\alph{section}}}}{}{}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
See appendix \ref{app}.

See \cref{app}

\appendix

\section{First appendix}
\label{app}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I try this with `memoir`, I get the error `Use of \refstepcounter@optarg doesn't match its definition.` Do you know what that could be?

Comment: @maero21: Unfortunately, I don't know the internals of `memoir`. Maybe a conflict with `cleveref`? What happens if you don't load it and remove `\cref`?